# how to place elements in matrix optimally so that distance from other elements is minimum?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, combinations

I have a matrix of order 7x4  I have 4 zeros in the matrix I want to place the zeros such that every other element has a minimum distance to one of the zeros? how should I approach the problem?

Comment: I think, divide a matrix into 4  submatrices and then put zero to the centre of each submatrix

Comment: How do you define "distance"?

Comment: As per my solution positions will be (1,1) (1,2) (5,1) (5,2)

Comment: @trincot distance is one unit between each element

Comment: How do you define "unit"? Is a diagonal step 1 or 2 units? What do you want to optimise? The average distance? The median distance? The number of cells that are at a minimum distance?

Comment: in my case , diagonal travel is not allowed so its vertical and horizontal . for example element [2,2]  is 2 units from [1,1]

Comment: What do you want to optimise? The average distance? The median distance? The number of cells that are at a minimum distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It becomes a more interesting problem for *programming* when the size of the matrix and/or number of zero-cells would be a variable input.

As a **first step** you would determine a lower bound for the maximum distance between a cell and a zero-cell. In the concrete case of a 7x4 matrix, we have 28 cells. We can choose 4 zero-cells.

Let's first try to reach every other cell with just one step (distance 1). Each zero-cell has 4 neighbors, so including itself it represents at most 5 cells that have a distance to it of at most 5. If they are all distinct, we can so find at most 4x5 = 20 cells that have a distance of at most 1 with a zero-cell. But we have 28 cells in the matrix, so that will never work.

If we take the same reasoning with a distance of 2, then each zero-cell can have 13 cells around (including itself) that have a distance of at most 2 to that zero-cell. So in a best case we could cover 4x13=52 cells. So it might be possible to find a solution with distance 2 (but it is not certain yet). That will be our lower bound for the maximum distance a cell may have with a zero-cell.

Secondly, register for each cell the neighbors it has with at most that distance from it.

Finally, perform this sequence of steps:

1. Choose a cell A that has the fewest neighbors. The first time this will be a corner cell (any of the four).
2. From A's neighbors choose the cell B that has itself the most neighbors. Place a zero in B and add this choice to the solution.
3. Remove all the cells that are neighbors of B, including itself, and remove them also from the neighbor-lists of other cells.
4. If we have repeated this 4 times (so we have placed 4 zeroes), check that there are no more cells left over. If so: solution found. If not, backtrack, and change the choice made in step 2 or step 1 to the second-best choice, ...etc. In the very worst case, you would also have to backtrack on minimum distance, and try with an increased distance. Note that for a 7x4 matrix, no backtracking will be necessary. A solution is found on the first attempt.
5. With the remaining cells, repeat from step 1.

Here is a visual representation of each step for the concrete 7x4 matrix:

[image]

To make this efficient, you would need to store the cells in a data structure that allows to identify the cell with most/least neighbors in constant time. A Min-Max Heap would be helpful, although with a small input array size like 7x4, it is probably not worth it.

Comment: Thanks, I read it thoroughly I may need to read it a few more times to convert it into code. Is it some known algorithm which I should learn to solve such problems in future.

Comment: In my opinion one learns by doing. The more programming problems you tackle, the more you get your intuition sharpened to take on the next one. I am actually sure that this particular problem would need more ideas for improvement if the input (the array, the number of zeroes) would become much larger.